# UIImagePickerController not displaying selected image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController which I am using in Ipad though when you select one of the images nothing happens here is the code for the picker:

```
- (IBAction)addPicture:(id)sender {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 753, 118);
    [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    patientPicture = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    UIImageView *pictureView = (UIImageView *)[imageCell viewWithTag:777];
    pictureView.image = patientPicture;
    [_imgViewAdd reloadInputViews];
}
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerController];
    popOverController.delegate = self;
}
```

What happens is the imagepicker loads fine though when I go to pick one of the pictures nothing happens at all

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

last instead of first.

Also...

```
@interface yourViewController ()<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

You didn't set the pickerController delegate...

```
pickerController.delegate = self;
```

Because you have a popover use this..

```
[popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm not sure it even calls the function as the picker just stays there and doesn't disappear

Comment: that worked great though it doesn't go away when you click an image any ideas

Comment: @OllieCole Do you have [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: yes I do have it though I suspect as it is a pop that it might be different

Comment: Yeah you must also add [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (it worked for me ) :

```
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo CALLED");

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        testImageView.image    = (UIImage*) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; //testImageView is a UIImageView 

    }];
```